# Multiple divs with 2 rows and unlimited columns

Tags: jquery, html

I have 10 divs coming from JSON data, I want to add a div after every 2 divs.
My HTML code is like this

```
<div class="imgs">
    <div class="fixed">1</div>
    <div class="fixed">2</div>
    <div class="fixed">3</div>
    <div class="fixed">4</div>
    <div class="fixed">5</div>
    <div class="fixed">6</div>
    <div class="fixed">7</div>
    <div class="fixed">8</div>
    <div class="fixed">9</div>
    <div class="fixed">10</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to group the divs in parent divs like this?

```
<div class="imgs"> 
    <div class="set">
        <div class="fixed">1</div>
        <div class="fixed">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="set">
        <div class="fixed">3</div>
        <div class="fixed">4</div>
    </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: research many website but i didn't get any answers.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried. Hint: Use wrap function. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simpler method:

```
while($('.imgs > .fixed').length) {
    $('.imgs > .fixed:lt(2)').wrapAll('<div class="set">');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/XW659/

Or:

```
$('.imgs .fixed:even').each( function() {
   $(this).next().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="set">'); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/VzgQC/

Comment: this was more simpler... TOOO Gooood.... :) thank you so much.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ehg8P/1/)

You haven't posted the JSON so this solution works on the HTML you've given.

You need to select the `div.fixed`s, chunk them into twos, create each `div.set`, move those elements into that and put that into `.imgs`. You don't need to clear out `.imgs` of those divs because append actually moves each item from where they were to where you specify.

```
$(function(){
    $('.imgs').each(function(){
        var $imgs=$(this);
        var $children=$(this).children();
        var $chunks=chunk($children, 2);
        $.each($chunks, function(){
            $('<div class="set">').append(this).appendTo($imgs);
        });
    });
});

function chunk (arr, len) {
  var chunks = [],
      i = 0,
      n = arr.length;
  while (i < n) {
    chunks.push(arr.slice(i, i += len));
  }
  return chunks;
}
```

Comment: You Nailed IT.... Very much appreciated.. :) thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = yourjson;
var set = 2;
var html = "";
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
   if (set++ == 2){
      set = 0;
      if (i != 0) // close only if one has been open
         html += "</div>";
      html += "<div class='set'>";
   }
   html += "<div class='fixed'>"+json[i]+"</div>"; // add .fixed
}
html += "</div>"; // close last .set

$("#container").html(html);
```